# boost::multi_array resize doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I can't get boost::multi_array resizing to work. When I try it, it gives errors about std::_Copy_impl and the like. Here is the code

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

typedef boost::multi_array<int, 2> array_type;

class arrayclass{
public:
    arrayclass(array_type::extent_gen extents)
        : multiarray(extents[3][4]){
    }
    array_type multiarray;
};

int main(){
    array_type::extent_gen extents;
    arrayclass arraytest(extents);
    arraytest.multiarray.resize(extents[5][6]);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Here are the errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: multiarray, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2216): error C2665: 'std::_Copy_impl' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2182): could be '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::input_iterator_tag,std::output_iterator_tag)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int,1>>,
1>              _InIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,const int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2191): or       '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::random_access_iterator_tag,std::random_access_iterator_tag)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int,1>>,
1>              _InIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,const int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<T,TPtr,NumDims,Reference>, boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<T,TPtr,NumDims,Reference>, boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<T,TPtr,NumDims,Reference>, boost::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<Category,Traversal>, boost::detail::iterator_category_with_traversal<Category,Traversal>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              TPtr=const int *,
1>              NumDims=boost::mpl::size_t<2>,
1>              Reference=boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              TPtr=const int *,
1>              NumDims=boost::mpl::size_t<2>,
1>              Reference=boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              TPtr=int *,
1>              NumDims=boost::mpl::size_t<2>,
1>              Reference=boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int,1>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              Category=std::input_iterator_tag,
1>              Traversal=boost::random_access_traversal_tag
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              Category=std::input_iterator_tag,
1>              Traversal=boost::random_access_traversal_tag
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2227) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_Iter,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::tr1::false_type)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int,1>>,
1>              _Iter=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,const int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>>,
1>              _InIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,const int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_45_0\boost\multi_array\view.hpp(321) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<T,TPtr,NumDims,Reference>,boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<T,T *,NumDims,boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<T,1>>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<int,1>>,
1>              T=int,
1>              TPtr=const int *,
1>              NumDims=boost::mpl::size_t<2>,
1>              Reference=boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>,
1>              _InIt=boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<int,const int *,boost::mpl::size_t<2>,boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<int,1>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_45_0\boost\multi_array\view.hpp(313) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<T,NumDims> &boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<T,NumDims>::operator =(const boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<T,NumDims> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              NumDims=2
1>          ]
1>          c:\badprogramer\multiarray\multiarray\main.cpp(7) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<T,NumDims>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              NumDims=2
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Replace `extents[5][6]` with `boost::extents[5][6]` in the call to `resize`.

Comment: No still skrews up. I'm following the tutorial/documentation on this one.

Comment: Very strange, I can copy-paste your code into the same compiler and it works.

Comment: It compiles under GCC 3.4.6 too.

Comment: Which version of Boost are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is reproducible with VS10 (using the proper VS10 headers) + boost 1.44 and in debug configuration (according to doc in older versions of boost as well).

The short workaround ([until next c++ SP](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/488103/error-with-boost-multi-array-version-1-40-when-compiling-with-ds-2010)) is to

```
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
```

before everything else (specifically before STL includes).

There are more complicated possible solutions - see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/3c9eac4f-86e4-490b-bbde-dbd70176b0f8) similar thread.

Cheers

Comment: I'm still having this issue even on version 1.67 of boost. Here's a very basic code sample (~20 lines). https://pastebin.com/h8D5JYLf that can reproduce the issue. Not sure what the next step is here.

Answer (score 4):

A bit stale thread, but I see this is an issue with even the most recent VS 2010 and Boost 1.47.0. This is in fact a problem with Boost.MultiArray, hard to believe, I know!

To fix, edit boost code:

- Open `boost/multi_array/iterator.hpp`
- Replace first occurrence of `boost::random_access_traversal_tag` (Line 57 in version 1.47.0)
  with `std::random_access_iterator_tag`
- Search second (line 75), replace that whole typedef with

  `typedef typename array_iterator::iterator_facade_ facade_type;`

hth

Comment: this is fixed in the upcoming version (1.49.0), and above fix I suggest is not quite safe. So, please upgrade!

Comment: Version 1.49 has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround, that solved my problem is replacing

```
array_type multiarray;
```

with

```
array_type* multiarray;
```

and whenever you need to resize your array use

```
delete arraytest.multiarray;
arraytest.multiarray = new array_type(extents[5][6]);
```